# Count of a count- PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, frequency

My table is as follows:

```
 guid version

 A1   lol
 A2   roflmao
 A1   lol
 A1   lol
 A2   lol
 A3   roflmao
 A3   roflmao
 A3   roflmao
 A3   roflmao 
 A3   roflmao
 A3   roflmao
 A4   roflmao
 A4   roflmao
 A5   lol   
 A5   lol
```

I want to count then number of times roflmao appear under 3 times (per GUID) in total.

So far I've the following but it's not outputting anything:

```
$sql="select guid,version, count(*) as `count` 
from mytable WHERE version = 'roflmao' group by guid having `count` < 3'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

 // Return the number of rows in result set

 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 printf($rowcount);

 // Free result set

 mysqli_free_result($result);
 }
```

Comment: Count(*)??? How is this supposed to work? Count(version) maybe?

Comment: Your query is fine. Simply remove closing single quote. [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a311c/2)

Comment: His query is not fine @fusion3k

Comment: @sagi see the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a311c/2)

Comment: Ok, so in this case he want the output to be 2 @fusion3k , look at my solution

Comment: OP want count “appear under 3 times“ and count is < 3 for A2 and A4. The query works fine.

Comment: No ! its not, you can even see it in the title 'count of a count' , he want to count how many are there that has under 3 times. @fusion3k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT guid
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE version = 'roflmao'
    GROUP BY guid
    HAVING COUNT(*) <3) t
```

This first select all the guids that has 'roflmao' appearing less them 3 times, and then counts the them.

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You have to add `as something` at the end.

Comment: @CodyRaspien I always forget mysql require to alias each subselect .. take it now it will work

Comment: No problem:) @CodyRaspien , No , you don't have to use "t" but you do have to use something, it can be whatever alias you want to give it, "a" "inner_table" "Cody" .